# Creating a File with no extension with right click on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, right-click, file-types

I've been trying to create a blank file type with right click. I managed to create HTML, CSS, JS and PHP extension files using the SHELL NEW process but i can't seem to do that with an entirely blank file type, so that once i have the chance to give it a name i also have the chance to give it it's file type. In other words i want to right right and have the option that when i right click and i go to new it will give me a blank file so that i can name it: **filename.FILETYPE**, so i can generate any number of files but right clicking and then naming them. I remember being able to do so in the past or when a file doesn't have a filetype preattached to it, when renaming it and giving it a .extension, it would then change the file to do just that. Please let me know if anyone has been able to do so or has a solution.

I attempted to do it by creating a Key of ShellNew under the * Folder, then creating a string value of NullValue with a Data Value of 1, but that did not work, i even created a key with an expandable string value but that also didn't work. I have tried different programs but they have all failed. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a file, *including its extension*:

- Click on the file.
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the name.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select the *whole* filename.
- Type *anything* (other than reserved characters such as <kbd>\</kbd>) to rename it as desired.

Windows allows you to change the file extension of any file, though in some cases it shows a warning, which you may blithely ignore (you can always change the name back, anyway):

[image: Change extension dialog]

Comment: thank you, i tried that method to rename, it did not change the extension

Comment: i realized that the extension was not available to me, so i added the option the explorer by going to VIEW>SHOW/HIDE and checking the box next to File Name Extensions, by doing so i was able to change the files extension and not just the name, thank you for that.